# Python - Comparing two CSV documents from the same python script from an update to another one

Tags: python, csv, compare, row

**Background** : With a Python Script, I scraping data (html) from a Website and put this data in a CSV document.

This CSV document looks like that :

```
Hong Kong;The Jardine Engineering Corporation Limited
Hong Kong;Towngas
Hong Kong;Tricor Services Limited
Hong Kong;UL International Limitied
Hong Kong;Urban Property Management Limited
Hong Kong;VTECH Corporate Services Ltd.
Vietnam;Cam Ranh Computer Co. Ltd
Vietnam;CFTP Company
Vietnam;Chevron Vietnam
```

First column : Country

Second column : Name

My file have more than 5000 rows.

**I need to compare this CSV document, to another one (from the same script, so same structure) to track the potential changes (if we have new lines, or removed one).** *The best will be to create a file with all the changes, or print them in the terminal.*

**REMEMBER that if something change in the CSV file (one more row) all the data gonna be shifted
**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you had a go at this yourself yet? Which bit are you stuck with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. :)

Your problem boils down to doing a diff between two lists. This is available in Python via [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html).

This example from the manual should help you:

```
>>> diff = ndiff('one\ntwo\nthree\n'.splitlines(1),
...              'ore\ntree\nemu\n'.splitlines(1))
>>> diff = list(diff) # materialize the generated delta into a list
>>> print ''.join(restore(diff, 1)),
one
two
three
>>> print ''.join(restore(diff, 2)),
ore
tree
emu
```

To print the changes to a file:

```
>>> s1 = ['bacon\n', 'eggs\n', 'ham\n', 'guido\n']
>>> s2 = ['python\n', 'eggy\n', 'hamster\n', 'guido\n']
>>> for line in unified_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='before.py', tofile='after.py'):
...     sys.stdout.write(line)   
--- before.py
+++ after.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-bacon
-eggs
-ham
+python
+eggy
+hamster
 guido
```

Comment: Seems perfect ! I'm trying that and come back in few minutes ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [GNU `diff`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). It is a command-line tool designed to do **exactly** what you want. GUI versions are available.

From Wikipedia:

> In computing, `diff` is a **file comparison utility that outputs the differences between two files**. It is typically used to show the changes between one version of a file and a former version of the same file. Diff displays the changes made per line for text files. Modern implementations also support binary files.[1] The output is called a "diff", or a patch, since the output can be applied with the Unix program patch. The output of similar file comparison utilities are also called a "diff"; like the use of the word "grep" for describing the act of searching, the word diff is used in jargon as a verb for calculating any difference.[citation needed]

Giving you the benefit of the doubt, you probably tried to Google for something like "*Find differences between two csv files from Python*". If you forget the fact the files are `csv` format, or that they were created using Python, a search for `find differences between text files` would have found GNU `diff` for you.

---

Edit:

Adding one line poses no problem for GNU `diff`. It will find the one line that changed, and tell you about it.

Example:

```
lws@helios:~$ cat file1
alpha
beta
charlie
delta
echo
foxtrot

lws@helios:~$ cat file2
alpha
beta
charlie
CHAMELEON
delta
echo
foxtrot

lws@helios:~$ diff file1 file2
3a4
> CHAMELEON
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I've already tried with Diff but when one row is new ... all is shifted so a lot of row are putted as new ... but they aren't .

Comment: @Carto_: My trivial example (above) gives the expected output when one line is inserted in the middle of a file. Can you post an example of your data where `diff` fails to do what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
OLD_PATH = r'/Users/abelrossignol/Desktop/1.csv'
NEW_PATH = r'/Users/abelrossignol/Desktop/2.csv'

out = open("Out.txt", 'w')

old = open(OLD_PATH, 'r')
old_lines = list(old)
old.close()

new = open(NEW_PATH, 'r')
new_lines = list(new)
new.close()

for line in unified_diff(old_lines, new_lines, fromfile=OLD_PATH, tofile=NEW_PATH):
    out.write(line)
    print("Writter")
```

Seems to work perfectly. I'm still trying to understand the structure of Out.txt but the most difficult is done.

Thank you very much for your help ;-)

I hope that might be helpful one day for another people.